# django - Permission denied in uploading photos

Tags: django, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

When I try to upload an Image, I am getting an error:

> OSError at /
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/project/django-user-activities/django_user_activities/static/media/uploaded_files/1422722471_11_Tulips.jpg'

I think its related with user permission. But since I am a windows user, and I am hosting this in a ubuntu 14.04 OS, I have no idea how to solve this. How do I resolve this problem/error? I would be very much grateful if you could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shotgun command for all permission problems:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/ubuntu/project/django-user-activities/django_user_activities/static/media/
```

Please note though that this is almost never a good idea...

Read this if you want to do it properly: https://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux

Comment: Fun fact: I once used a security hole, that I created myself with `chmod 777`, to regain root access of a server; got what I came for, patched the hole, and left (seriously, this is a bad idea) :)

Comment: Is it... OMG! Can you please update your answer how to do that? Do I just need to `chgrp -R www-data /var/www`. I didn't understand as I am a windows user.

Comment: In this particular case, you have nothing to worry about, unless you're running on a multi user system and you don't trust the other users not to mess with the data of this particular directory.

Comment: I just don't want to be irresponsible about the handing out of shotguns. :)